# Link between soudness, completeness, and the use of truth tables

Tags: logic

I do think there is a link, I just can't quite catch it.

I have looked it up but I'm pretty new to logic so the explanations all seemed a little confusing. I think a system needs to be sound and complete in order to rely on truth tables to make proofs but I couldn't be less sure.

Comment: What have you looked up? There is plenty of information on this online, and this question exhibits no obvious effort.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm sorry I edited it

Comment: Yes, there is. For propositional logic, sound and complete means that the system proves all and only tautologies.

Comment: Truth tables are models of theories. Completeness and soundness relate models of theories to the proof system

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is meant by "all"? Meaning we can't create a tautology in that system wich is unprovable? But then unprovable from what axioms?

Comment: See [Sound and Complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698441/sound-and-complete) as well as [Proof of completeness and soundness of a proof system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403842/proof-of-completeness-and-soundness-of-a-proof-system)

Comment: But truth table method works **only** for propositional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth tables are used in defining the notion of logical. consequence. A conclusion $C$ is a *logical consequence* of a set $\mathcal H$ of hypotheses if, whenever an assignment of truth values to the propositional variables (a row of a truth table) makes all the hypotheses in $\mathcal H$ true, it also makes $C$ true.  Notice that this definition of logical consequence is entirely about truth values; there is no mention of axioms or rules of inference.

A conclusion $C$ is *deducible*, in a formal system $X$, from a set $\mathcal H$ of hypotheses if there is a deduction of $C$ from hypotheses in $\mathcal H$ and axioms of $X$ by means of the rules of inferencee of $X$. Notice that this definition of deducible is entirely about axioms and rules of inference; there is no mention of truth values.

The notions of "logical consequence" and "deducible in $X$", despite their entirely different provenance, turn out to be equivalent provided $X$ was intelligently designed.

In more detail, $X$ is said to be *sound* if "deducible in $X$" implies "logical consequence", and $X$ is said to be *complete* if "logical consequence" implies "deducible in $X$". So the combination of soundness and completeness is the equivalence mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Comment: So a system only needs to be complete to make proofs using truth tables?

Comment: @NathanKaufmann If the system $X$ is complete and if you can infer $C$ from $\mathcal H$ using truth tables, then there will exist a deduction of $C$ from $\mathcal H$ using the axioms and rules of $X$. So if "make proofs" in your question means guarantee that a proof (using $X$) exists, then the answer is yes. But if "make proof" means to actually write down a deduction, then (depending on the details of $X$) considerable work might still be needed. Knowing that a deduction exists doesn't guarantee that you can easily produce one.

Comment: Thank you very much!